# MongoDB Aggregation query with multiple group bys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hope you can help I am new to aggregation queries.

I have a nested data structure that I want to group to produce statistical output. I have a set of orders where the order is for a country, product and product code. An order looks like:

```
>db.orders.findOne();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5efc6db38cb109193e41c4d3"),
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2020-06-25T02:06:25.428Z"),
    "data" : {
        "nested" : {
            "country" : "France"
        },
        "product" : "Product 4",
        "latest" : {
            "sub" : {
                "code" : "Code 3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have an aggregation query that groups by country, product and code.

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
{
    $unwind :{
        path: "$data.nested.country"
    }
},
{
   $group: {
       _id: { country: "$data.nested.country", product: "$data.product", code: "$data.latest.sub.code" }
   }
}
])
```

This produces output such as:

```
    { "_id" : { "country" : "Slovenia", "product" : "Product 3", "code" : "Code 7" } }
    { "_id" : { "country" : "Japan", "product" : "Product 1", "code" : "Code 9" } }
    { "_id" : { "country" : "Japan", "product" : "Product 4", "code" : "Code 4" } }
    { "_id" : { "country" : "China", "product" : "Product 1", "code" : "Code 1" } }
    { "_id" : { "country" : "France", "product" : "Product 3", "code" : "Code 4" } }   
    { "_id" : { "country" : "Japan", "product" : "Product 4", "code" : "Code 8" } }
    { "_id" : { "country" : "Japan", "product" : "Product 4", "code" : "Code 5" } }
    { "_id" : { "country" : "Slovenia", "product" : "Product 4", "code" : "Code 4" } }
    { "_id" : { "country" : "Slovenia", "product" : "Product 4", "code" : "Code 7" } }
    { "_id" : { "country" : "Slovenia", "product" : "Product 4", "code" : "Code 2" } }
    { "_id" : { "country" : "China", "product" : "Product 4", "code" : "Code 8" } }
    { "_id" : { "country" : "France", "product" : "Product 4", "code" : "Code 4" } }
    { "_id" : { "country" : "Japan", "product" : "Product 2", "code" : "Code 3" } }
    { "_id" : { "country" : "Japan", "product" : "Product 2", "code" : "Code 6" } }
    { "_id" : { "country" : "Japan", "product" : "Product 2", "code" : "Code 3" } }
    { "_id" : { "country" : "Slovenia", "product" : "Product 2", "code" : "Code 9" } }
    { "_id" : { "country" : "China", "product" : "Product 2", "code" : "Code 6" } }
```

I want to group this data by country and then product and then code so, for example, Japan would have a list of products i.e. `Product 4, Product 2` inside each there would be a list of codes so `"Product 4": ["Code 8","Code 5","Code 3","Code 6","Code 2"]` etc. Since an order can be made for a Product with a particular code more than once for a country I need I think a map of codes and the counts for each code.

```
    { "_id" : { "country": "Japan", products: [{"product":"Product 2","codes":[{"code":"Code 3","count":2},{"code":"Code 6","count":1]}]
```

Comment: @thammada.ts you were very helpful with another post of mine. Can you help please?

Comment: I guess you got it sorted out with the help of @Joe?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.  You shouldn't need an `$unwind` stage unless you expect data.nested.country to be an array in some of the orders.

The group stage you have is a good first step, you just need to add a counter:

```
{$group: {
    _id: { 
          country: "$data.nested.country", 
          product: "$data.product", 
          code: "$data.latest.sub.code" 
    },
    count: {$sum:1}
}}
```

That leaves you with distinct country+product+code with a frequency count of each.
Then group by country and product, collecting all of the code values with their counts into an array:

```
{$group: {
    _id: { 
          country: "$_id.country", 
          product: "$_id.product" 
    },
    codes:{
           $push: {
                   code:"$_id.code", 
                   count:"$count"
           }
    }
}}
```

This leaves you with each product having an array of codes with their counts.
Lastly, group by country, and collect the products into an array:

```
{$group: {
    _id: { 
          country: "$_id.country" 
    },
    products: { 
          $push:{
                product:"$_id.product", 
                codes: "$codes" 
          },
    }
}}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KfyPeth07yD)

Comment: Many thanks for this and explaining each stage so well. I'd also like to be able to sort the results :). I'd like to be able to sort by country, then product and then codes. At which stage do I do this?

Comment: Add a $sort stage at the end.

Comment: Thanks. I've realised that "data.latest" is supposed to be an array of sub documents - "latest": [{ "sub": { "code": "Code 3" } }]. If I change to this then in output the code value is a string inside of an array - "codes": [{ "code": ["Code 3"], "count": 1 }] i.e. "Code 3" instead of ["Code 3"]. How can I do this?

Comment: If you want to consider each code separately, add `{$unwind:"$data.latest"}`  before the first group